# Is $f(x,y) = \frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}$ Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Is $f: [-1,1]^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}} & \text{ if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
 0& \text{ if } (x,y)= (0,0)
\end{cases}$ $\lambda _{2}$-integrable over $[-1,1]^{2}$?

It is Lebesgue measurable, because it is continous on $[-1,1]^{2}$ with exception on (0,0). But this one point doesn´t matter for the measurability. Is it Lebesgue-integrable, though?

Comment: What does that $\lambda_2$ mean?

Comment: @ArcticChar Presumably $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If it were,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{|x^{2}-y^{2}|}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}dxdy&\geq\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\dfrac{|x^{2}-y^{2}|}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}dxdy\\
&\geq\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\dfrac{y^{2}-x^{2}}{(2y^{2})^{2}}dxdy\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{1}{y}-\dfrac{1}{4y^{4}}\dfrac{y^{3}}{3}dy\\
&=\dfrac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{y}dy\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: So this is wrong?

Comment: The integral doesn't converge, and I don't see any problems in your work. I will upvote your answer to counter the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. First integrate w.r.t. $r$ and then w.r.t. $\theta$. You will see easily that the function  is not integrable.

Comment: I did not see the exponent of the den